# NCBI Blast databases - cannot find some databases

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, blast, public-databases, ncbi

I'm working with a system that does local BLAST searches using some preconfigured BLAST databases.  From what I see, these were updated within the last year, but I cannot find any current databases available that have those same names.  One specific set is a non-redundant set of human protein or nucleotide sequences.  The databases are named human_nr and human_nt (with various extensions as per the BLAST db format).  There are others names up_sp_human (Uniprot-Swissprot human?) and up_tbl_human (Uniprot-Tremble human?), but a cannot find any similar databases on the NCBI site or other sites.

Where else should I look for such preconfigured databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a human_nr or human_nt database for NCBI.

An equivalent database is accessible via the standard `nr/nt` database and simply restrict the organism parameter to `human` or to taxa id `9606` . This essentially will do the same thing.

Or maybe this sort of thing?,

```
blastdbcmd -db nr -entry all -outfmt "%g %T" | awk ' { if ($2 == 9606) { print $1 } } ' > human_flat-list.db
```

Comment: This is super helpful!  I'm guessing these were custom prepared similar to what you describe.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @KirkD-CO